# Mention a BSD License library in my iPhone App

Tags: licensing

I am using two libraries which are under **BSD Licence**. How do I link/mention them in the legal text of my iPhone App? Do i even have to mention them in the app?

Can someone offer the missing text.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all written in the license / copyright statement. You need to follow the licensing terms. If you have problems to understand it, consult a lawyer that can go through the text with you and answer all your questions interactively.

The other option is that you contact the original author and ask her about the usage terms and conditions your concrete question(s).