# How do I find the text that I have to include in my mobile app as licenses for different libraries im using?

Tags: ios, licensing

My app uses the following external libraries:

- Google maps
- AWS
- Fabric
- Crashlytics
- SwiftyJSON
- LogglyLogger
- Digits
- TwitterCore
- Braintree

But I simply can't seem to find the text that I have to include in my app for each of these licenses, if there is any at all. How do I find this?

Comment: Each project should contain a LICENSE file or similar.

Comment: @rmaddy so I just copy and paste that??

Comment: Essentially. Many apps have an "About" page or something similar with a license section. There you can list each library followed by its actual license. How you do it is really up to you and not all libraries/licenses require you to even mention that it's being used.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663035/mention-a-bsd-license-library-in-my-iphone-app